# How to remove html tags of data exported to excel on ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, excel

I am trying to export a table to excel but I get the data like this:

```
<a href='filename.aspx?oecl_id=3'>1</a>
<a href='filename.aspx?oecl_id=62'>2</a>
```

Because I am printing the data just like that:

```
cell = new HtmlTableCell();
cell.InnerHtml = "<a href='filename.aspx?oecl_id=" + rsCont.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString() + "'>" + rsCont.Rows[i]["PENDING"].ToString() + "</a>";
```

So how can I get just the numbers on excel? In this example 1 and 2.

I am printing the data like this but this just remove the "" at the end of each row:

```
        foreach (HtmlTableCell celda in fila.Cells)
        {
            if (celda.InnerHtml.IndexOf("</a>") > 0)
            {
                cell = row.Cells.Add(celda.InnerHtml.Remove(celda.InnerHtml.IndexOf("</a>")));
            }
            else
            {
                cell = row.Cells.Add(celda.InnerHtml);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/drafts/98280) for example. All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I just made another hidden table without the links, just with the data, like this:

```
<table id="table_excel" style="display:none" runat="server">
    <tr>
        <th>Column1</th>
        <th>Column2</th>
        <th>Column3 >50</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```